# AWS RDS Downsize mysql database without losing users and their passwords

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

AWS doesn't let you shrink DB storage. If this is required, they suggest to either user their Migration Service or use mysqldump.
See the following [Docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-db-storage-size/)

The Migration Service doesn't create an exact replica (e.g. issues with auto increment fields as raised on this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138946/aws-dms-creates-tables-with-no-auto-increment).
so `mysqldump` seems better solution.

I am aware that the `mysqldump` needs to exclude the default and I am also happy with copying the permissions across (e.g. see this [link](http://bluechiptek.com/blog/scripting-the-migration-of-aws-rds-mysql-databases)), but this requires the users to exist in the first place.

How do I move all the users across (without knowing or resetting their passwords)?

Comment: Look at the triggers RDS creates on the grant tables (e.g. mysql.user).  Some actions are blocked but I don't think you're prevented from inserting rows.